# Python not reading .xlsx file in Unicode

Tags: python, html, excel, unicode, utf-8

I am using xlrd (Python3) to read in an excel spreadsheet, which I then write the content (text strings) of each cell into an html file. I can open the html file in a browser, but the unknown characters (" , $ ) are replaced by the diamond with a question mark. Also, my HTML editor (brackets) does not support non utf-8 files. I have tried to save the excel spreadsheet as unicode, I have tried some basic python decode() and encode() functions, and I have tried to force xlrd's encoding_override setting to read in Unicode.

Any easy fixes that would force the script to read/decode the excel text cells into unicode so I can properly edit and publish the HTML outputted by the program?

Comment: Try adding an encoding header to the generated html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Try using `iconv` on generated HTML when it's ready

Comment: that sounds strange. xlsx-Files are Unicode by default. Can you show us a sample code?